# Using the quip automation API to create a quip document that contains a live app

Tags: liveapps, quip

I want to be able to create a live app when creating a new quip document using the quip automation API.

[Quip API](https://quip.com/dev/automation/documentation#document-post)

It looks like you can only use HTML and markdown when creating the document

```
curl https://platform.quip.com/1/threads/new-document -d "content=<h1>See If can imbed live app</h1><p>First+paragraph</p><p>@calendar</p>" -H "Authorization: Bearer authcode“
```

So the above is a curl example using the API. I can't see how to imbed a liveapp in a new document?

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Automation API does not appear to support creating documents with Live Apps in them at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

There is a brand new "Copy-Document" API coming up in Quip, through which you can copy the contents of a pre-defined template while creating a Quip document.

First, you need to create a template in Quip which contains your Live App. Then use the "Copy-Document" API to create a new document using the template.

**Step 1: Create Template Document**

Create a Quip document and add placeholders anywhere in the document with the format [[placeholder_name]]. For example, the title could be Account Plan for [[AccountName]].

**Step 2: Create a document from the template via API**

*Endpoint*

POST https://platform.quip.com/1/threads/copy-document

*Arguments*

This endpoint takes the following values:

- thread_id (required) - Id of thread to be copied (must be a document)
- folder_ids (optional) - List of ids of folders where the new thread will be found. If not supplied, the authenticated user's private folder will be used.
- member_ids (optional) - List of ids of users to be added to the thread. The authenticated user will always be a member on the document.
- title  (optional) - A string value to be the title of the new document. If this isn't the same string as the first section in the doc, it will get overwritten with the first section when the document is saved.
- values (optional) - String or file containing a JSON dictionary whose keys are strings and values are strings. Keys can only contain the characters. The request body is in FORM URL-ENCODED FORMAT, and values is a stringified JSON which has to be URL encoded.

*Response Fields:*

On success, this endpoint returns a dictionary of the following form:

- { thread: { id:  }}

**sample request**

```
POST /1/threads/copy-document HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer <<YOUR TOKEN>>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Host: platform.quip.com

thread_id=4F7GAdx5qHbE&title=My+Copied+Document&values=%7B%22AccountName%22%3A%22Imagini%22%7D
```